# Run detekt on all builds

Tags: android, detekt

It's possible to run detekt before build? (run, release...)

I followed this https://arturbosch.github.io/detekt/gradletask.html

But `check.dependsOn detekt` on build.gradle (app) don't do nothing...

I already tried `check.dependsOn detekt` and `preBuild.dependsOn detekt`

And tried `...dependsOn detektCheck` too...

What's the error?
I can't use the detektCheck task before build?

Answer (score 2):

You can add *detekt task* before *build* in **Run Configuration**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One other option is to added it as a part the build, so it could fail the build:

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded {
    if (name == "compileDebugKotlin") {
        dependsOn(tasks.detekt)
        mustRunAfter(tasks.detekt)
    }
}
```